# Writing a Perl hash to disk to be read by Python

Tags: python, perl, cross-language

How can I write a Perl hash to file, in such a way that it can be read from Python?

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my %h = (
   foo => 'bar',
   baz => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
   raz => {
       ABC => 123,
       XYZ => [4, 5, 6],
   }
);

dumpHash('/tmp/myhash', %h);
```

... and

```
#!/usr/bin/python
h = readHash('/tmp/myhash')
print h

# {
#  'foo': 'bar', 
#  'baz': ['a', 'b', 'c'],      
#  'raz': {
#          'ABC': 123, 
#          'XYZ': [4, 5, 6]
#         }
# }
```

I normally use Perl's built-in `Storable` to serialize hashes. I see Python has a [Storable reader](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/storable/), but it's not part of the standard distribution.

Is there a way to do this with standard built-ins from both languages.

Comment: Use JSON or YAML or ...

Comment: Why don't you consider about using json format?

Comment: I've never used Perl before, but my suggestion would be to dump it to json. Then in python you can use `json.loads` to load it to a dict.

Comment: JSON should work. Libraries for it ship with the core distro of both languages.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only mechanism for this that ships with Perl is `Storable` which of course Python doesn't know about. I'll probably just suck it up and install Perl's JSON module.

Comment: @ysth, It does since 5.14. "JSON::PP was first released with perl v5.13.9"

Comment: @ikegami: thanks (this comment will self destruct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the 'builtin' requirement on first read of your question, but I digress. `JSON` is not a built-in in Perl, so you'll have to install via `CPAN`. Nonetheless, this is probably one of the most efficient and compatible ways to do it.

Perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use JSON;

my $file = 'data.json';

my %h = (
   foo => 'bar',
   baz => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
   raz => {
       ABC => 123,
       XYZ => [4, 5, 6],
   }
);

my $json = encode_json \%h;

open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;

print $fh $json;

close $fh or die $!;
```

Python:

```
import json

file = 'data.json';
data = json.loads(open(file).read())

print(data)
```

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution with only built-in stuff, but I think you're right that I might as well bite the bullet and grab a CPAN module

Comment: Just don't name your Python script `json.py` or it'll conflict with the actual json module.

Comment: If you're going to install JSON(.pm), you might as well install JSON::XS and use that instead.